# Remote Desktop to Server 2016 fails after disabling TLS 1.0

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

For some reason Remote Desktop is failing to connect to Server 2016 from Server 2008 R2 after disabling TLS 1.0.

I can connect to other 2008 R2 servers from it
I can connect to the 2016 server from as Win 10 laptop (so the service is working fine)

Can ping the server both on the public and private networks
Can ping the Server Name

Tried ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: 1. Anything in the event log? 2. Do you have the latest RDP client? 3. Have you checked the RDP configs on the 2016 server? maybe there's some limitation. 4. Where exactly the connection fails?\

Comment: 1. Nothing in the logs 2. I assume this is automatically updated (ass me?) but I will look into that 3. Nothing changed since the last time it worked 4. No idea - how do I find out?

Comment: Went to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=41984 to update the RDP client for Server 2008 R2 - message was update was not applicable (so assume it's the latest version for this platform)

Comment: Tried to login from another Server 2008 R2 box and that won't connect either! We did update the 2016 box for the latest PCI specs - TLS 1.1 and 1.2 - Triple DES 168, AES 128/128, AES 256/256 - MD5, SHA, SHA 256, SHA 384, SHA 512 - Diffie-Hellman, PKCS, ECDH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to add RDS support for TLS 1.1 and 1.2

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080079

Comment: The only downloads on that site are for windows 7 and 2008.  When I get the 2008 one, it says "This patch is not applicable to your computer."  Is there a fix for Windows 2016?

Comment: This was a fix for Server 2008 R2 failing to connect to Server 2016. Server 2016 should have support for TLS baked in.